# What does it mean that something has a hard edge to it?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, idiom-meaning

I'm reading an article in the New York Times (the author recently had a daughter) and it talks about being an Asian person in America today. It reads:

> But now, while my wife slept at night, I would stand over our daughter’s bassinet, compare her face at one week with photos of myself at that delicate, lumpen age and worry about what it might mean to have an Asian-looking baby in this America rather than one who could either pass or, at the very least, walk around with the confidence of some of the half-Asian kids I had met — tall, beautiful, with strange names and **a hard edge to** their intelligence.

<sup>Source: [The Myth of Asian American Identity](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/10/05/magazine/asian-american-identity.html) — behind a paywall</sup>

I looked up "hard edge" online, and I found "hard-edged" as an adjective, which is often referred to strong personality in a good way. I can't understand how it is used here though, since it is referred to their intelligence. Does it possibly mean "sharp"? I know "sharp intelligence" to be a very common collocation.

However, it seems to me that "hard-edged" is only used very often to express something that has been said as "sarcastic/cutting/caustic". Does it mean that they are often cheeky and capable of commanding respect through witty and clever remarks? I don't know, I'm just trying to make sense of it.

Comment: Know anyone who is smart, but a bit mechanical? Never rude, but not warm? Entitled but not demanding? That's hard-edged, like many New Yorkers I grew up with.

Comment: @YosefBaskin You, of course, have more knowledge than me of the term as it relates to New Yorkers but as a Brit I read it as meaning that the half-Asian kids have a greater degree of resoluteness and what is called 'steely determination' than children of other ethnic backgrounds. Am I completely wrong?

Comment: It mostly means bold, Ben.

Comment: Street smart, perhaps? If you don’t have access to the author, you’ll just have to go with the vibe.

Comment: When someone writes for a prestigious newspaper, such as the New York Times, he or she feels obligated to be a bit abstruse in the way they express themselves. I wouldn't be surprised if the writer was once accused of being hard-edged!

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately I still have no clue about it. I gather that the author was simply hinting at a generic sharp/hard component of the intelligence of these people. Maybe they have a way with words to stand up for themselves, express their criticism ... Maybe it's something like edgy.

Comment: Yes, edgy. Not an IQ issue, but an attitude and posturing issue. Not harsh, and not a pushover. The contrast in the passage is between the softer affect of Asians and the tougher mode of part-Asians.